# Wordpress Plugin Localization

Tags: plugins

Here is my problem, i am trying to translate plugin. I use plugin locale hooke

```
add_filter('plugin_locale', 'pls_locale', 10, 2);
```

next function wich return language de_DE

```
   function pls_locale() 
    {
       $pls_language = get_option('jezik');
       return $pls_language;  
    }
```

finally translate strings something like this

```
__('text', 'myplugin');
```

But i have major problem, when i try to change my language in my plugin, also lang on otheres plugins are changed.

Also i cant use load_plugin_textdomain() function because it depends on WPLANG constant, wich change also admin lang, wich i dont want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The filter comes with the text domain as second argument. So you could do this:

```
function wpdev_170138_plugin_locale( $locale, $domain )  {

    if ( $domain === 'myplugin' ) {
        return get_option( 'jezik' );
    }

    return $locale;
}

add_filter( 'plugin_locale', 'wpdev_170138_plugin_locale', 10, 2 );
```

Now only your plugin's locale is changed.